# How to run HHVM in Docker as a daemon?

Tags: docker, hhvm

`HHVM` does not go into background when running it in Docker using `hhvm -m daemon`. The process starts but does not return me to command prompt. `ctl^c` kills the process. My workaround is as follows:

1. Install `screen`
2. Run `exec >/dev/tty 2>/dev/tty </dev/tty`
3. Run `screen`
4. Run `HHVM` from `screen`

Any idea why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You've probably solved this since you asked the question (or the issue has since been fixed in recent versions of hhvm), but I'll add some thoughts as I was just doing this as well.

## Daemon mode (`hhvm -m daemon`)

Seems to work as expected currently (Ubuntu 12.04):

```
root@5ba718633f3a:~# hhvm -m daemon
Log file not specified under daemon mode.\n\n
root@5ba718633f3a:~# ps aux | grep hhvm
root       123  0.8  9.7 554212 36388 ?        Ss   21:33   0:00 hhvm -m daemon
```

## Detached server mode (`hhvm -m server &`)

```
root@5ba718633f3a:~# hhvm -m server &
[1] 151
root@5ba718633f3a:~# ps aux | grep hhvm
root       151  2.3 11.5 631128 43212 pts/0    Sl   21:36   0:00 hhvm -m server
```

## Server mode w/supervisord

In your supervisord config:

```
[program:hhvm]
directory=/var/www
command=hhvm -m server
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
```

Assuming you use supervisor, that option is probably the most painless, unless you're needing to start/stop ad hoc hhvm instancess.  Also, I'm sure you're aware, but the `directory` option in the supervisord process config can be replicated via hhvm CLI args as well (so it's not CWD-based), e.g.:

```
hhvm -m daemon -v Server.SourceRoot=/var/www
```

Hope that helps.  Sorry for the late reply!